# IP camera viewer

Tags: software-recommendation

Hey there I am looking for an application to view our IP camera. We have a web interface, but it sucks and takes forever to load. I know there are several Windows options available, many of them even free. I have not had any luck finding one for Ubuntu though.

To be clear, this is not for a webcam, but rather a wireless IP camera. Also, I am not looking for a recording server, just a handy viewer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short put

`http://IPAddress:port#/videostream.cgi?user=username&pwd=password`

in a text file and name it security.asp and open it with vlc.

[Ref](http://onlinetechadvice.blogspot.com/2011/01/stream-ip-camera-vlc.html)

Comment: Since we don"t know what camera model the person asking uses, I don't think we should generalize that URL. Different vendors, different concepts.

Comment: Your right.  I dont have the cameras to test, dont know the model, and now that you mention it it may not work with PSIA standard ip cams.

Comment: This is great, Thanks Matt!!! It lacks all camera controls but gives me the ability to instantly view what is going on in my Baby's room. 

For the sake of clarity, I am using a Foscam FI8910W. 

With that in mind, if anyone does know of linux software that contains tilt/pan controls, that would make my year!

Comment: No idea how it would work, but a quick search with the model number. (and some breadcrumb trails) turned up this: http://www.zoneminder.com/

Comment: Does this work for ANY ip camera? I tried mine but it doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

VLC has been the easiest way I've found for my super-cheap noname camera. I use the option to view a "Network Stream" and enter the feed URL for my camera. NOTE: This is NOT the web interface page to your camera.

Use this method to determine the URL for your video feed:

- Pull up the web interface for viewing the camera image/video
- Use the "View page source" option in your browser (usually available via right mouse button, anywhere on the page)
- Search the page source for "rtsp" (Real Time Streaming Protocol) URLs

My URL looks like this, but YOURS MAY BE DIFFERENT!

```
rtsp://username:password@ip_addr/live0.264
```

If you don't want to hardcode your credentials in the URL, you can omit them and VLC will prompt you for them.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will be help

I have my Ipcams set to view in CCTV plugin available in google chrome browser.
I use Foscams. `http://username:password@IPADDRESS:PortNo/video.cgi`
single click you have all of them.

Answer (score 0):

different camera vendors have different formats for the `rtsp` links. There is no common format for the rtsp link and depends on your hardware manufacturers. But the basic requirements remains the same 
Camera IP address 
Username 
Password

Following link has most of formats covered 
https://support.ipconfigure.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005588503-Using-VLC-to-test-camera-stream

Comment: I understand your point but the question didn't mention any specific requirements so the scope of the ans is very big.  There would be no other option than copying the complete list from there and that too is not good I guess. Plus one basic format link is already given above. The main focus of my answer is the rtps links are not fixed and depends on brands/ manufacturers that one needs to find out.

Comment: Fair point. I'll remove my comment